# How to convert result set properties to string?

Tags: javascript

I used $SPServices() to return resultset from a calendar with many recurring events. Instead of changing my CAML query, I want to select only certain rows from the result set using JavaScript. I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
Var units = ($this.attr(ows_Unit);
Var n = units.indexOf"x");
alert(n);
```

Why alert(n); does not pop up an alert on screen?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a parenthesis, line 2 should be:

```
Var n = units.indexOf("x")
```

Normally the browsers developer tools (F12 in IE or Chrome) will help you find errors like this by spitting an error message out in the JavaScript Console

Edit:

Your first line seems incorrect as well, should be:

```
var units = $(this).attr(ows_Unit);
```

Comment: Please note though that this code will return an integer indicating the position of "x" in Units